# How to disable google chrome blocking scripts over https?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a site and I need to upload script in the head section like:

```
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&mode=debug&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Google Chrome browser pops up the message "There is a content on the site that may be offencive bla bla bla", 
I`ve tried to set this script through https protocol, but the same thing heppens.
How to avoid this feature in Chrome?

Comment: Of course it means - avoiding via scripts, not in browser itself.

Answer (score 2):

Locally mirror the script from your own site and reference it that way.  It is likely getting the "offensive" warning based off of the URL of the script.

If you need several versions of the script you could write a shell script to synchronize all of the versions that you need on a regular basis.

Your new script reference should look something like this:

`<script src="js/yandex.api.package.full.debug.ru-RU.js" type="text/javascript"/>`

Comment: + 1. worked perfectly for me. Was getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: MQA is not defined ` error on calling mapquest api js file over https