# https preventing google adsense ads from showing?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ads, adsense

Ok, so recently i setup an SSL on my website, and when i visit my website via `https://` the ads on my site (served via adsense) won't load.... But if i re-visit my site using `http://` the ads start appearing again.. Could this possibly be caused by my `.htaccess` file? Here take a look

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Options -Indexes
```

This is leaving me quite perplexed, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having problem of malicious script which was blocked in https scheme

please refer

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en

[How to disable google chrome blocking scripts over https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911195/how-to-disable-google-chrome-blocking-scripts-over-https)

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1208336?hl=en